# How to negate integer value in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am performing a Select on 5.7.32 where I want to negate the values:

```
SELECT (val * -1) AS new_value
```

This results in the error:

> ```
> Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range i
> ```

How can this be overcome?

Comment: Well, why would the data type `BIGINT UNSIGNED` if you need the value to be negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip rows where it is out of range:

```
select -val as new_value from foo where val <= 9223372036854775807
```

or you can just treat it as a string:

```
select concat('-',val) as new_value from foo;
```

casting to signed will not work, since it will change values larger than 9223372036854775807 to be negative numbers, which when negated will be positive.

You could convert it back to a number with:

```
select 0+concat('-',val) as new_value from foo;
```

but that will lose precision for large numbers.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9f39c6a0ac79d2eaddf0eef5de20ca04)

Answer (score 1):

You can `cast` to `signed` first:

```
select cast(val as signed) * -1 as new_value from mytable
```

Note that you could also phrase this as:

```
select - cast(val as signed) as new_value from mytable
```

---

Confusingly enough, both following expressions work fine, without explicit casting:

```
select - val as new_value from mytable;
select val / -1 as new_value from mytable;
```

---

Note that unsigned datatupes have a maximum allowed value than the equivalent unsigned (basically that's the same number of possible values, but also including negative values). So basically, as commented by Bill Karwin, values greater than the max 32-bit signed integer will not be correctly processed.

Comment: @ysth: we can get that error with any `unsigned` value (other than `0`). See: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v42SJCyPZ6Vux5HWjKnZBY/0

Comment: ah, you are correct.  I messed up my testing.

Comment: seems `-val` only fails when there are too large values, but `val * -1` always fails?  I don't understand this.

Comment: Note this will truncate BIGINT values greater than the max 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: @BillKarwin no, it doesn't truncate, at least in 5.7, it just treats >= 2**63 as negative instead of positive.

Comment: @BillKarwin: yes that's a good point. I edited my answer to mention that.

Comment: @ysth: yes, it is somehow inconsistent that the multplication raise the error but not direct negation, or even division...